# Change date after add calendar to database

Tags: java, mysql, date, docker

When I try to add new time entry to my db application first days was changed and destroy hierarchy. First two days of my week was changed.

I try to change time zone from CET to UTC and CEST

When I Post days from 25 - 31 days in DB return:

```
2019-03-25
2019-03-25
2019-03-27
2019-03-28
2019-03-29
2019-03-30
2019-03-31
```

But next when I use postman to get this week it's return:

```
{

    "day": "SUNDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-24",
    "hours": 0,
    "status": "SAVED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "SUNDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-24",
    "hours": 5,
    "status": "REJECTED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "MONDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-25",
    "hours": 9,
    "status": "REJECTED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "TUESDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-26",
    "hours": 9,
    "status": "SAVED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "WEDNESDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-27",
    "hours": 9,
    "status": "SAVED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "THURSDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-28",
    "hours": 9,
    "status": "SAVED",
    "comment": ""
},
{
    "day": "FRIDAY",
    "date": "2019-03-29",
    "hours": 9,
    "status": "SAVED",
    "comment": ""
}
```

My DB driver is :

```
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=CET
```

Comment: Hi, I am afraid it is not very clear what your question is here.

Comment: I can add that I use docker Maybe docker settings or db settings have other time zone cofiguration but maybe somebody was resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct data types.

## `DATE`

In MySQL, your table column should be of type [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

This type is akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE` for date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone.

## `LocalDate`

Retrieve your date string value as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), as shown on Stack Overflow many many times already.

The `LocalDate` class has no time zone, so you should see no adjustments.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" )
```

Or:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( date_col , LocalDate.class ) ;
```